Build failed because <yourproject>.swiftmodule is not built for arm64, please try a run destination with a different architecture
I got this error when I simply tried to run tests. I have my project set to run via arm 64 architecture.

I was able to avoid this error by choosing a different simulator to run the tests, one that included (Rosetta).


this works for me, really strange issue because some scheme can use regular simulator while other only able to run on rosetta simulator. not sure what's the difference, do you found any way to make it able to build with regular arm64 simulator?

But how can it work without Rosetta?

i met this situation on archive
